# Javacript only executed on first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have javascript code included in my sharepoint site. When I load the page the first time, it is executed, but when I load it the second time, it is not running. It get's loaded in correct order but the functions inside are not executed (but only on second load)

The first time I load the page by entering the url in the webbrowser, the second time I load the page by clicking the link inside sharepoint website (same url). It seems to me that this problem occurs because it is not a complete pageload. Looks like some ajax magic to me.

This is how I have implemented the js ressources:
In my **aspx file** I have those lines:

```
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~site/SiteAssets/js/jquery.min.js" OnDemand="false" runat="server" Localizable="false" LoadAfterUI="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~site/SiteAssets/js/newoverview.js" OnDemand="false" runat="server" Localizable="false" LoadAfterUI="true"/>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration3" Name="<% $SPUrl:~site/SiteAssets/css/newoverview.css%>" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:RssLink runat="server"/>
```

**jquery.min.js**

```
function $_global_jquery() {
    //jQuery code goes here
}

$_global_jquery();
```

**newoverview.js**

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse");
function runAfterEverythingElse(){
   /*  my code */ 
   html = 'test';
   jQuery('table[summary="test"]').html(html);  
}
```

Take note that my code is working, as I can see it working when loading the page the first time!

**The question**
Why is the javascript not executed when opening the page inside sharepoint?

Comment: Does it run too soon if you put your html modification code in side jQuery ready? I.e., $(function() { // your code }

Comment: @JussiPalo No, I had that before but it made no difference.

Comment: You most probably have the Minimal Download Strategy Feature enabled, disabling that is quickest way to "workaround" this issue unless you really need/want to have that enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

There is an alternate answer beside my long answer. But this answer is shorter, more reliable and faster. The only downside of this method: the code is executed very often.

```
function myCode() {
    // custom code (e.g. jQuery) goes here
} 
$("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event) {
      myCode();
});
```

### Explanation

The bind method is listening for dom modification on the element with id #DeltaPlaceHolderMain. Partial reloads are doing dom mods and thus the code is being executed!

Answer (score 5):

If you have Minimal Download Strategy enabled, you need to do it like this:

```
$(function () {
      ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
          if (typeof asyncDeltaManager != "undefined")
            asyncDeltaManager.add_endRequest(runYourCode);
          else runYourCode();
      }, "start.js");

  });

function runYourCode() {
    //your code
     return false;
}
```

[Source](http://blog.symprogress.com/2013/09/sharepoint-2013-execute-javascript-function-after-mds-load/)

Comment: The code is broken now, when I add it like this. Do I need a file called `start.js` or what is start.js? And do I need the `return false`? Do I need to modify `ScriptLink `attributes (LoadAfterUI etc.)?

Comment: start.js is related to MDS, so it should be there if you use MDS.

Comment: The code doesn't get executed now (even on first load). But it is loaded in correct order: `start.js` -> `jquery.min.js` -> `newoverview.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I see `newoverview.js` is included with attribute LoadAfterUI = true.

However, `runAfterEverythingElse()` is a `<body>` 'onload' event (if I understand the point of '_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames' correctly).

So is it possible that there is a conflict between the  body 'onload's firing, and the time the UI is considered 'ready', and there's a timing issue somewhere?

To test the theory out, get rid of the `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` altogether by replacing `newoverview.js`'s contents with:

```
   jQuery(function() {
       /*  my code */ 
       html = 'test';
       jQuery('table[summary="test"]').html(html);
   });
```

and optionally change `newoverview.js`'s LoadAfterUI to false - this attribute shouldn't make any difference

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still the same error occurs. I changed `LoadAfterUI` to false and changed the content of `newoverview.js`. Code works. But only on first load.

Comment: Sorry Peter. Frustrating.

Comment: A page load is a page load - it's starting from scratch each time. Therefore there should be no difference between first and second, unless:
1) a cookie has been set the first time that affects load 2, or;
2) the link you speak of from the sharepoint URL isn't a straightforward link. Verify this link is a vanilla `<a href="your-page-URL"...>` rather than some sneaky JS doing something else.

Comment: I can see that it is not a straightforward link. The page is not doing a complete reload, it is more like a partial-load. Menu on left side does not change, but the content-area is loaded again or changes. 
Try it yourself: open a sharepoint 2013 website and click `documents` or `tasks` on left menu. This is what I do. And **most important**: my javascript file is loaded (but not executed)!

Comment: Typical MS/Sharepoint: overcomplicating everything unnecessarily In that case, I would just use a script tag in your ASPX file itself, at the bottom:

       <script type="text/javascript>
       jQuery(function() {
           /*  my code */ 
           html = 'test';
           jQuery('table[summary="test"]').html(html);
       });
       </script>

and remove the 'push' onto _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames (and even the ScriptLink of newoverview.js)

Comment: `<script>` tag is not allowed in aspx in sp2013.

Answer (score 0):

### Long answer

Finally this is my solution to make jQuery, DOM Manipulation and MDS work alltogether in Sharepoint 2013.

### aspx file

```js
<asp:content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~site/SiteAssets/js/jquery.min.js" OnDemand="false" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~site/SiteAssets/js/mycustom.js" OnDemand="false" runat="server" Localizable="false"/>
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration3" Name="<% $SPUrl:~site/SiteAssets/css/newoverview.css%>" runat="server"/>
    <SharePoint:RssLink runat="server"/>
</asp:content>
```

### mycustom.js

```js
function myCode(){
    // jQuery code goes here
    // you can use $ namespace
}

function preCode(){
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(myCode);
}

if(typeof _spPageContextInfo != "undefined" && _spPageContextInfo != null){
    var jsURL = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/sharepointsite/siteassets/js/mycustom.js";
    RegisterModuleInit(jsURL, myCode());
}else{
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(preCode, "sp.init.js"); 
}
```

### Explanation

***Issue 1:*** Partial Load (MDS)
Sharepoint Minimal Download Strategy is a feature which does a lot of caching for you and - to achieve that - does partial site loads. Which has the sideeffect of unexecuted javascript.
The **mycustom.js** file makes use of `_spPageContextInfo` which will be *`defined`* when the site got loaded using mds. When that happens we need to register our script to mds to make it load - `RegisterModuleInit`. The script will be loaded again and JS code will be executed then.

***Issue 2:*** Multiple events after `document.ready`
We can not use document.ready for dom manipulation as sharepoint is doing a lot of things after document.ready. The last event triggered is `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded` which is wrapped in a function because it can't be called directly as further Sharepoint JS files need to be loaded before.

*a side-note*
The **aspx file** is loading the JavaScript files by using `SharePoint:ScriptLink`. I removed `LoadAfterUI="true"` to avoid future side effects and to have unified settings for all javascript files. Thus it defaults to `LoadAfterUI="false"`.

### Credits

1. [ASPX: ScriptLink.LoadAfterUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.scriptlink.loadafterui.aspx)
2. [JS: blogs.c5insight.com (Kyle Wright)](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/entryid/455/account-for-sharepoint-2013-s-minimal-download-strategy-with-your-custom-javascript)
3. [JS: josharepoint.com (José Quinto)](http://josharepoint.com/2015/06/16/custom-javascript-function-loaded-after-the-ui-has-loaded-in-sharepoint-2013/)