# Top Naviation Menu is not loaded when script runs - SharePoint Foundation 2013 Oslo Master Page

Tags: javascript, master-page, quick-launch

I am trying to find the Top Navigation menu elements that are in the top part of my master page.  So at the bottom of my master page I have added a script to fine the element on the page as follows:

```
var menulist = document.getElementById("zz14_RootAspMenu");
```

However, the value of menulist is always undefinded.  If appears the content page has not finished loaded yet.

I have tried the following to delay the execution of the script but none have worked so far:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', function () 
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(processmenu(), "sp.js");
$(document).ready(function ()
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE -----
Here is the html from the rendered page that contains the element I an trying to get a reference to:

```
<div class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox" id="zz13_V4QuickLaunchMenu" onclick="return AjaxNavigate$OnClickHook(event, this);">
    <ul class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static" id="zz14_RootAspMenu">
        <li class="static selected"><a tabindex="0" class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Home</span><span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a tabindex="0" class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/SitePages/Association.aspx"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Association</span></span></a></li><li class="static"><a tabindex="0" class="static ms-quicklaunch-dropNode menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode ms-droppable" aria-dropeffect="move" href="/SitePages/Board of Directors.aspx" DropId="4"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Board</span></span></a></li><li class="static dynamic-children"><span tabindex="0" class="static dynamic-children menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow dynamic-children" aria-haspopup="true"><span class="menu-item-text">Recent</span></span></span><ul class="dynamic">
            <li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" class="dynamic ms-quicklaunch-dropNode menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode ms-droppable" aria-dropeffect="move" href="/Policies/Forms/AllItems.aspx" DropId="5"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Policies Library</span></span></a></li><li class="dynamic"><a tabindex="0" class="dynamic ms-quicklaunch-dropNode menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode ms-droppable" aria-dropeffect="move" href="/Contracts/Forms/ActiveContracts.aspx" DropId="6"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">Contracts Library</span></span></a></li>
        </ul></li><li class="static ms-verticalAlignTop ms-listMenu-editLink ms-navedit-editArea"><span class="ms-navedit-editSpan" id="zz13_V4QuickLaunchMenu_NavMenu_Edit"><a class="ms-navedit-editLinksText" id="zz13_V4QuickLaunchMenu_NavMenu_EditLinks" onclick="g_QuickLaunchMenu = null; EnsureScriptParams('quicklaunch.js', 'QuickLaunchInitEditMode', 'zz13_V4QuickLaunchMenu', 1, 2, 0, 'sid:1025'); cancelDefault(event); return false;" href="#"><span class="ms-displayInlineBlock"><span class="ms-navedit-editLinksIconWrapper ms-verticalAlignMiddle"><img class="ms-navedit-editLinksIcon" src="/_themes/6/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=8"></span><span class="ms-metadata ms-verticalAlignMiddle">Edit Links</span></span></a><span class="ms-navedit-menuLoading ms-hide" id="zz13_V4QuickLaunchMenu_NavMenu_Loading"><a title="This animation indicates the operation is in progress. Click to remove this animated image." id="zz13_V4QuickLaunchMenu_NavMenu_GearsLink" onclick="HideGears(); return false;" href="#"><img id="zz13_V4QuickLaunchMenu_NavMenu_GearsImage" src="/_layouts/15/images/loadingcirclests16.gif?rev=23"></a></span><div class="ms-navedit-errorMsg" id="zz13_V4QuickLaunchMenu_NavMenu_ErrorMsg">

        </div></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

UPDATE -- 
So have created a js file that I am trying to have run after the content of the master page loads using the RegisterModuleInit function. All my code is below:

```
Type.registerNamespace('MenuStuff')
MenuStuff.Functions = MenuStuff.Functions || {};
MenuStuff.ibUserInRole = false;

MenuStuff.Functions.menutohide = function (menutext) {
    var menulist = document.getElementById("zz14_RootAspMenu");

    alert("menulist :" + menulist);
    // Iterate LIs
    for (var itemi = 0; itemi < menulist.childNodes.length; itemi++) {
        var item = menulist.childNodes[itemi];
        if (item.nodeName == "LI" && item.innerHTML.indexOf(menutext) !== -1) {
            item.style.display = "none";
            break;
        }
    }
}

MenuStuff.Functions.checkRights = function (groupId) {
    try {
        MenuStuff.ibUserInRole = false;
        var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
        var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" };

        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups(" + groupId + ")/users/getbyid(" + userId + ")",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: requestHeaders,
            success: userInRole,
            error: userNotInRole
        });
        function userInRole(data, request) {
            // if we reach here, the current user belongs to the group Id 7 for the example
            MenuStuff.ibUserInRole = true;
        }
        function userNotInRole(error) {
            MenuStuff.ibUserInRole = false;
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    }
}

MenuStuff.Functions.processmenu = function () {
    //error here
    MenuStuff.Functions.checkRights(6);  
    if (MenuStuff.ibUserInRole == false) {
        MenuStuff.Functions.menutohide("Board");
    }
}

RegisterModuleInit(
    _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + 'Site Assets/newmenuscript.js',
    MenuStuff.Functions.processmenu);

alert("Before ProcessMenu again");
MenuStuff.Functions.processmenu();
```

I am using an Ajax Namespace per the information in this article [http://www.wictorwilen.se/the-correct-way-to-execute-javascript-functions-in-sharepoint-2013-mds-enabled-sites][1]

However my menulist is still null.  Any suggestions??

UPDATE: I used the sample code the Alan provided and added the following to the end of my master page right before the end body tag.  I updated the element to find as the ID of the item had changed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("menuToHide");

    function menuToHide()
    { 
        var menulist = document.getElementById("zz13_V4QuickLaunchMenu");
        alert("menulist: " + menulist); 
    }
</script>
```

With this code, when Minimal Download Strategy (MDS) was enabled, the alert never occurred.  When I disabled MDS, the alert worked.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of HTML that shows the zz14_RootAspMenu element you are trying to retrieve? Is this element loaded when the page is rendered, or loaded dynamically?

Comment: Is this SP 2010 or 2013?

Comment: SP Foundation 2013 - Oslo Master Page.  I will update the question also

Comment: Paste a full snippet of your javascript code also.

Comment: Jim I posted the line of code that is generating the error.  It is the get element by ID.  I know this works correctly because if I copy the HTML I provided into a HTML page in Visual Studio, remove all the CSS Class information, then add the get element by ID line in a script block at the end of the page, I can debug the page and it finds the element..

Comment: I would walk up the DOM to see what SharePoint is actually doing. Try getting the element with id `zz13_V4QuickLaunchMenu` and do a `console.log` of the `childNodes` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get anything to fire AFTER all the content was loaded.  What I had to do was use a JavaScript setTimeout function and wait for the content to finish loading.  For anyone that this can help, my final code is below.  I placed in a .js file in my Site Assets library and included it after the jquery library at the end of my Oslo master page.  So far things seem to be working

```
var iobj_menuList = null;
var ii_Count = 0;
var ib_UserIsAdmin = false;
var ib_UserIsARB = false;
var is_BoardMenuItem = '<li class="static"><a tabindex="0" class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/Site Board Pages/Board Of Directors.aspx"><span class="additional- background ms- navedit - flyoutArrow"><span class="menu- item - text">Board</span></span></a></li>';
var is_ARBMenuItem = '<li class="static"><a tabindex="0" class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" href="/Site ARB Pages/Architectural Review Board.aspx"><span class="additional- background ms- navedit - flyoutArrow"><span class="menu- item - text">ARB</span></span></a></li>';

function checkRights() {
    try {
        var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
        var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" };
        var groupID1 = 6;

        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups(" + groupID1 + ")/users/getbyid(" + userId + ")",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: requestHeaders,
            success: userIsAdmin,
            fail: userNotAdmin,
            error: userNotAdmin
        });

        function userIsAdmin(data, request) {
            // if we reach here, the current user belongs to the group Id 7 for the example
            ib_UserIsAdmin = true;
            processmenu();
        }
        function userNotAdmin() {
            var groupID2 = 35;
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups(" + groupID2 + ")/users/getbyid(" + userId + ")",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: requestHeaders,
                success: userIsARB,
                fail: UserNotInARB,
                error: UserNotInARB
            });
            function userIsARB(data, request) {
                // if we reach here, the current user belongs to the group Id 7 for the example
                ib_UserIsARB = true;
                processmenu();
            }
            function UserNotInARB(error) {
                //user is not a member
            }
        }
        function AdminPermissionError(error) {
            alert("AdminPermissionError: " + error);
        }

    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    }
}


function processmenu() {

    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($(".ms-quickLaunch") === "undefined" || ii_Count > 10) {
            ii_Count = ii_Count + 1;
            processmenu();
        }
        else if (ii_Count > 10) {
            alert("Menu Load timed out.")
        }
        else {
            //Append the board menu option
            var lobj_ItemToAdd = null;

            if (ib_UserIsAdmin)
            {
                lobj_ItemToAdd = is_BoardMenuItem;
            }
            else if (ib_UserIsARB)
            {
                lobj_ItemToAdd = is_ARBMenuItem;
            }
            $(lobj_ItemToAdd).insertAfter(".ms-quickLaunch li:eq(1)");            
        }
    }, 300);
}

checkRights();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this yet?

**remove:**
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', function () 
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(processmenu(), "sp.js");
$(document).ready(function () ...

**replace with:**
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("menuToHide")

Comment: Yes I tried that and the code never fired.  It appears to be related to the minimal download strategy

Comment: The minimal download strategy only smooth the load time when you access a new page. I don't think that the cause. Is there any custom script running during page load? I am using SharePoint 2013, I just tried in oslo.html master, it works for me.   
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>-->
        <script>
          _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("menuToHide");
          function menuToHide() {
          var menulist = document.getElementById("zz12_V4QuickLaunchMenu");
          console.log(menulist);
         }
        </script></body>
jquery-1.11.2.min.js is used in my environment.

Comment: If you don't mind, you are welcome to send me your master (.html), I'll see if I can replicate in my environment.

Comment: Thanks Alan.  I think following the information in this thread related to MDS will work.  I am still in the middle of testing it.  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222658/master-page-script-only-executes-once/222666#222666

Comment: thanks, let us know if you fix the problem, I am quite keen to know the cause of this.

Comment: I will try your script.  You did put it just before the end body tag from what I see.  I will try again.  Was about to resort to a javascript loop.  One more question, you are editing your master page in SharePoint Designer 2013 correct?

Comment: Alan - I updated the question with new updates from my tests